# Setting a custom font to all labels in a view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

In Xcode 4, it's not possible to set the Font Family of a view's labels through Interface Builder if the font is not installed in the OS or doesn't appear in the list of fonts in IB.

Since all the labels in certain views use the same font, I need to know if there's a simple and fast way of setting all of them to the same font family, instead of going one by one setting its family font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can you use an IBOutletCollection. Create a collection and connect all your labels to it in IB. Then in code just use setValue forKey. No idea if it's more efficient or not, but you don't have to loop through subviews.

```
.h
IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;

.m
UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:14];
[labels setValue:newFont forKey:@"font"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over each entry in the subviews array property of the view in question. For every one, check if it is a `UILabel` (send `isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]`). If it is, you can set the `font` property to a suitable font object.

Comment: Great, but that's what I didnt want to do. If there's no other way to do it, i'll take it...

Comment: You could try the iOS 5 only `appearance` proxy, though I can't find any documented evidence the font property of `UILabel` is appearance proxyable. I'll have an experiment later.

Comment: Had a quick look - no `UILabel` properties are marked as supported by the appearance proxy system. So, looping over everything seems to be your best bet.

Comment: This will not detect Labels inside subviews.